# How do I sort a Set based on an object's property?

Tags: swift, sorting, set

I am using Core Data in my project and I have an Team entity that contains a Set of Monsters. Each monster has an id property which is an Int16 type.

How do I take a set of Monsters and sort them based on each Monster's ID in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fun sort(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) -> Bool)`.
e.g.

```
struct Monster{
   var id: Int
}
var arr : Array<Monster>= []

for i in 0..<5{
   let monster = Monster(id: i)
   arr.append(monster)
}

for m in arr{
   print(m.id)
}
arr.sort { (monsterA, monsterB) -> Bool in
   return monsterA.id > monsterB.id
}

for m in arr{
   print(m.id)
}
```